# Loading a text file into a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, load

I am trying to load data into a listbox in a windows form application in c#. I have code from my main form which will put the data onto the listbox as followed...

```
namespace HRApplication
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    // The file used to store employee details
    string employeesFile = "employees.txt";

    // The collection used to hold the employee data
    Employees employees;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employees = new Employees();
        if (!employees.Load(employeesFile))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to load employees file");
        }
        else
        {
            PopulateListBox();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateListBox()
    {
        listBoxEmployees.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Employee employee in employees)
        {
            listBoxEmployees.Items.Add(employee.lastName + ", " + 
         employee.firstName);
        }
        //listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

from this I have a class called Employees where I am trying to get the load method working here is the code I have and any help would be very helpful.

```
namespace HRApplication
{
public class Employees : List<Employee>
{ 

    public Employees()
    { }


    public bool Load(string employeesFile)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
            return true;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question? What's wrong in your code?

Comment: sorry, its not showing up in the list box and wondered why?

Comment: Because you loop over a List of Employees but you add your lines to a List of Strings. Please add the essential code of the Employee class

Comment: I have these in my employee class - what code needs to go in and where sorry?

        string _firstName;
        string _lastName;
        string _address;
        string _postCode;
        string _phoneNumber;
        DateTime _dateOfBirth;

Comment: When you load the file, you need to split the line (string.Split) then with the parts obtained build an Employee instance. Add this instance to the base class of Employees (it is a List of Employee)

Comment: sorry, but I am very very confused, is there anyway of you emailing or something to explain it more at all?

Comment: The fundamental problem I see in your code is that you're reading the file in Load method and adding them to String list which is scoped to that method. Secondly, I don't see where you're having Iterator defined which iterates over Employee collection within Employees class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, for simplicity that your Employee class is something like this.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string lastName {get;set;}
    public string firstName {get;set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return lastName + ", " + firstName;
    }
}
```

Now, when you load a line of  text from the file you should split it in the parts that represent the employee data. Use that data to create an instance of the employee class and add the instance to the base class of Employees (a `List<Employee>`)

```
public bool Load(string employeesFile)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("employees.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Suppose that your line is splittable using a comma...
            string[] temp = line.Split(',');

            // This is really simplicistic. In a real world scenario
            // you should check if the line contains correctly all the 
            // fields required to populate an Employee...
            Employee emp = new Employee() 
            { 
                 firstName = temp[0], 
                 lastName=temp[1]
            };

            // This class is derived from List<T>
            // so you can use the Add method 
            // to add the employee to itself...
            Add(emp);
        }
        return true;
       }
    }
}
```

At this point your loop to populate the listbox should work (I use the ToString() overload to hide the building of the text for the ListBox)

```
private void PopulateListBox()
{
    listBoxEmployees.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Employee employee in employees)
    {
        listBoxEmployees.Items.Add(employee);
    }
    //listBoxEmployees.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I had to change the comma to a | as thats  how my data is split, but it is working correctly now. Thank you Very much!!